# Pyspark transformation: Column names to rows

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm working with pyspark and want to transform this spark data frame:

```
    +----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
    | TS | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth1 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth1 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth1 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth1 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth2 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth2 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth2 | ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth2 |
    +----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
    | 1  | some_value                    | some_value                    | some_value                    | some_value                    | some_value                    | some_value                    | some_value                    | some_value                    |
    +----+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

to that:

```
+----+-----+-----+------------+------------+
| TS | VAL | UNT |    sth1    |    sth2    |
+----+-----+-----+------------+------------+
|  1 |   0 |   0 | some_value | some_value |
|  1 |   0 |   1 | some_value | some_value |
|  1 |   1 |   0 | some_value | some_value |
|  1 |   1 |   1 | some_value | some_value |
+----+-----+-----+------------+------------+
```

Any idea how I can do that using some fancy transformation?

Edit:
So this is how I could solve it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, struct, lit
import re

df = sc.parallelize([(1, 0.0, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1), (2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3)]).toDF(["TS", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth2"]) 

newcols = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(".", "_"), df.columns))
df = df.toDF(*newcols)

cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in ["TS"]))
kvs = explode(array([struct(
                            lit( re.search(re.compile(r"VAL\[(\d{1,2})\]"),c).group(1) ).alias("VAL"),
                            lit( re.search(re.compile(r"UNT\[(\d{1,2})\]"),c).group(1) ).alias("UNT"),
                            lit( re.search(re.compile(r"([^_]+$)"),c).group(1) ).alias("Parameter"),
                            col(c).alias("data")) for c in cols
                    ])).alias("kvs")

display(df.select(["TS"] + [kvs]).select(["TS"] + ["kvs.VAL", "kvs.UNT", "kvs.Parameter", "kvs.data"]).groupBy("TS","VAL","UNT").pivot("Parameter").sum("data").orderBy("TS","VAL","UNT"))
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
| TS | VAL | UNT | sth1 | sth2 |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
|  1 |   0 |   0 |    0 |  0.7 |
|  1 |   0 |   1 |  0.6 |  0.2 |
|  1 |   1 |   0 |  0.1 |  0.4 |
|  1 |   1 |   1 |  0.4 |  0.1 |
|  2 |   0 |   0 |  0.6 |  0.8 |
|  2 |   0 |   1 |  0.7 |  0.3 |
|  2 |   1 |   0 |  0.1 |  0.1 |
|  2 |   1 |   1 |  0.5 |  0.3 |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

How can it be done better?

Comment: Demonstrate what you have done so far. `SO` is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I could solve it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, struct, lit
import re

df = sc.parallelize([(1, 0.0, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1), (2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3)]).toDF(["TS", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth2"]) 

newcols = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(".", "_"), df.columns))
df = df.toDF(*newcols)

cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in ["TS"]))
kvs = explode(array([struct(
                            lit( re.search(re.compile(r"VAL\[(\d{1,2})\]"),c).group(1) ).alias("VAL"),
                            lit( re.search(re.compile(r"UNT\[(\d{1,2})\]"),c).group(1) ).alias("UNT"),
                            lit( re.search(re.compile(r"([^_]+$)"),c).group(1) ).alias("Parameter"),
                            col(c).alias("data")) for c in cols
                    ])).alias("kvs")

display(df.select(["TS"] + [kvs]).select(["TS"] + ["kvs.VAL", "kvs.UNT", "kvs.Parameter", "kvs.data"]).groupBy("TS","VAL","UNT").pivot("Parameter").sum("data").orderBy("TS","VAL","UNT"))
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
| TS | VAL | UNT | sth1 | sth2 |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
|  1 |   0 |   0 |    0 |  0.7 |
|  1 |   0 |   1 |  0.6 |  0.2 |
|  1 |   1 |   0 |  0.1 |  0.4 |
|  1 |   1 |   1 |  0.4 |  0.1 |
|  2 |   0 |   0 |  0.6 |  0.8 |
|  2 |   0 |   1 |  0.7 |  0.3 |
|  2 |   1 |   0 |  0.1 |  0.1 |
|  2 |   1 |   1 |  0.5 |  0.3 |
+----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

Now at least tell me how it can be done better...

Comment: wrt your last line: I'd recommend you to ask a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want critique. Stack Overflow focuses on fixing broken code, and your code isn't broken (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good (upvoted). The only thing I would really do is extract the essential parts from the column names in one regex search. I’d also remove a superfluous `select` in favor of `groupBy`, but that’s not as important.

```py
import re

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, explode, array, struct, col

df = sc.parallelize([(1, 0.0, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1), (2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3)]).toDF(
    ["TS", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth1",
     "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth1", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[0].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[0].UNT[1].sth2",
     "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[0].sth2", "ABC[0].VAL.VAL[1].UNT[1].sth2"])

newcols = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(".", "_"), df.columns))
df = df.toDF(*newcols)


def extract_indices_and_label(column_name):
    s = re.match(r"\D+\d+\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)[^_]_(.*)$", column_name)
    m, n, label = s.groups()
    return int(m), int(n), label


def create_struct(column_name):
    val, unt, label = extract_indices_and_label(column_name)
    return struct(lit(val).alias("val"),
                  lit(unt).alias("unt"),
                  lit(label).alias("label"),
                  col(column_name).alias("value"))


df2 = (df.select(
    df.TS,
    explode(array([create_struct(c) for c in df.columns[1:]]))))

df2.printSchema()  # this is instructional: it shows the structure is nearly there
# root
#  |-- TS: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- col: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- val: integer (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- unt: integer (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- label: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)

df3 = (df2
       .groupBy(df2.TS, df2.col.val.alias("VAL"), df2.col.unt.alias("UNT"))
       .pivot("col.label", values=("sth1", "sth2"))
       .sum("col.value"))

df3.orderBy("TS", "VAL", "UNT").show()
# +---+---+---+----+----+                                                         
# | TS|VAL|UNT|sth1|sth2|
# +---+---+---+----+----+
# |  1|  0|  0| 0.0| 0.7|
# |  1|  0|  1| 0.6| 0.2|
# |  1|  1|  0| 0.1| 0.4|
# |  1|  1|  1| 0.4| 0.1|
# |  2|  0|  0| 0.6| 0.8|
# |  2|  0|  1| 0.7| 0.3|
# |  2|  1|  0| 0.1| 0.1|
# |  2|  1|  1| 0.5| 0.3|
# +---+---+---+----+----+
```

If you know a priori that you will have only the two columns `sth1` and `sth2` that will be pivoted, you could add these to `pivot`’s `values` parameter, which will improve the efficiency further.

Comment: Thx for your review Oliver

Comment: By the way, @Lossa, it’s likely that you wouldn’t need to resort to this parsing, if the way this DataFrame was generated is altered. But you’d need to show that piece of the code. Still, the code you showed does work and is about as efficient as it gets.